# Old game, possibly called "Demons"

Tags: identify-this-game

Does anyone know an old game, probably from 1980s or early 1990s where the player goes through a top down labyrinth opening secret rooms, collecting treasure, and food, and keys, trying to get to a different floor. The enemies rats and some star-looking things?

The player could also shoot what looked like mushrooms, but was probably throwing axes or something like that. There were some walls that could be broken by the mushrooms to gain access to a secret room. I also remember that the player had 1000 HP to start, which seemed like a lot.

I believe I played on a 286 or a 386 PC.

P.S.
I don't think it was Gauntlet (Gauntlet has way more elaborate graphics) or Wizard of Wor

Comment: I'm commenting after @snips-n-snails answer, which I have no reason to dispute.  This is a general comment.  There have been a large number of "Rogue-like" or "Moria-like" games, offered on most home computer systems since the 80s or before.  The involve much of what you describe, but also randomly generated dungeons so each play-thru is different. Graphics varied from pure ASCII characters to more sophisticated screens with a recognizable hero and monsters.

Comment: @RichF Yeah, that's why I has such trouble finding it, there are so many labyrinth/maze games in that time period, and the word "Demons" doesn't narrow it down much either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like [Demon Stalkers (1987)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJpWgfn_udw).

Comment: Yes, that's the one, thanks, I immediately remembered those yellow rats as soon as I saw the video